# Method calls out of order

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having problems with 2 methods execution.

one method I Send a file by `FTP` and the second method I rename this file.

so, the second method can only execute after the 1st method.
but the second method is executing before the 1st(causing crash, so the programa doenn't find the file)...

I just call the methods in order, ps:

```
[self sendFile];
[self renameFile];
```

Comment: Is the contents of sendFile synchronous? How do you send the file?

Comment: Post your code for sendFile

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing asynchronous transfer then make sure that you call the `[self renameFile];` method in the finishing block of your file transfer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the transmission is an asynchronous process. Usually (via delegation or a completion block), mechanisms are available to handle the completion of asynchronous processes. You would want to do the file rename when the transmission completion is signaled.

Answer (score 0):

For FTP transactions on iOS use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). The library can easly be built for iOS. Check this github project.

FTP upload goes then like this (with renaming after uploading): http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html
Libcurl is used widely and is extremely stable.